# Show tables with display none and block inside a sweetalert2

Tags: html, css, angular, sweetalert2

I'm programming HTML inside a sweetalert with TypeScript, and I want to show and hide a table when clicking on an item of the list. I tried with display none and display block but it doesn't work.

I have two differents div, one div has the following list

```
 '<div class="page" style="display:flex !important; flex-direction:row !important; height:100vh !important;">'+
        '<div class="sidebar" style="flex:1 !important; border:solid black 1px !important; height:100% !important;" >'+
           '<ul class="list-group">'+
            '<li class="list-group-item" for="show"><span>Acceso a Universal</span></li>'+// acceso a universal deberia mostrar la tabla al darle click pero no hace nada ppor lo mismo del style que falta de aplicar.
            '<input type="radio" id="show" name="group" style="display: none !important;">'+//creamor un radio para poder seleccionar desde el span
            '<li class="list-group-item" for="show1">Carga de Información</li>'+
            '<input type="radio" id="show1" name="group" style="display: none !important;">'+
            '<li class="list-group-item" for="show2">Reportes</li>'+
            '<input type="radio" id="show2" name="group" style="display: none !important;">'+
            '<li class="list-group-item" for="show3">Banco de Archivos</li>'+
            '<input type="radio" id="show3" name="group" style="display: none !important;">'+
            '<li class="list-group-item" for="show4">SITI</li>'+
            '<input type="radio" id="show4" name="group" style="display: none !important;">'+
         '</ul>'+
        '</div>'+
```

and the other div has the following table

```
'<div id="contenido" style="display:none !important;">'+'<table  class="table table-hover mb-0" style="border-collapse: separate !important;hight:border-spacing: 500px 500px!important;" >'+
            '<tr style="font-size: 12px !important;text-align:left !important;">'+
            '<th>Tipo de Permiso</th>'+'<th>Tipo de Permiso </th>'+'<th>Tipo de Permiso</th>'+'</tr>'+
            '<tr style=" font-size: 12px !important; text-align:left !important;"><td>'+accesoUniversal[0]+'</td>'+'<td>'+ accesoUniversal[1] +'</td><td>'+ accesoUniversal[2] +'</td></tr>'+'</table>'+'</div>'+
```

I based on the following example https://codepen.io/sekane81/pen/XbEVYv

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a Javascript function to change the `display` value of the table. Some kind of `onChange` function that uses the value of the checked radio button.

The Codepen example only works because the inputs and affected DIV are siblings, so you can use the sibling combinator `~`. There's no CSS method of moving up through parents to get to some other element.